# How to comment out an XML Element (using minidom DOM implementation)

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I would like to comment out a specific XML element in an xml file. I could just remove the element, but I would prefer to leave it commented out, in case it's needed later.

The code I use at the moment that removes the element looks like this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse(myXmlFile)
for element in doc.getElementsByTagName('MyElementName'):
if element.getAttribute('name') in ['AttribName1', 'AttribName2']:
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
f = open(myXmlFile, "w")
f.write(doc.toxml())
f.close()
```

I would like to modify this so that it comments the element out rather then deleting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution does exactly what I want.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse(myXmlFile)
for element in doc.getElementsByTagName('MyElementName'):
    if element.getAttribute('name') in ['AttrName1', 'AttrName2']:
        parentNode = element.parentNode
        parentNode.insertBefore(doc.createComment(element.toxml()), element)
        parentNode.removeChild(element)
f = open(myXmlFile, "w")
f.write(doc.toxml())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [beautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Read target tag, create appropriate comment tag and [replace](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another) target tag

For example, creating comment tag:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
hello = "<!--Comment tag-->"
commentSoup = BeautifulSoup(hello)
```