# Match "without this"

Tags: python, regex

I need to remove all `<p></p>` that are only `<p>`'s in `<td>`.
But how it can be done?

```
import re
text = """
    <td><p>111</p></td>
    <td><p>111</p><p>222</p></td>
    """
text = re.sub(r'<td><p>(??no</p>inside??)</p></td>', r'<td>\1</td>', text)
```

How can I match `without</p>inside`?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. Please...

Comment: You can look at BeautifulSoup as an actual (X)HTML Parser, but attempting to manipulate HTML with regex is a __bad__ idea.  You're only asking for headaches.

Comment: What should I use for this problem? Wouldn't DOM be overkill?

Comment: Hi, Qiao. See this post on why not parse with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: About parsing html with regexes, see the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Qiao: Why? Any amount of tag soup can make a DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html). I stole the following snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699745/how-to-comment-out-an-xml-element-using-minidom-dom-implementation) which you should be able to modify and work for you:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse(myXmlFile)
for element in doc.getElementsByTagName('MyElementName'):
    if element.getAttribute('name') in ['AttrName1', 'AttrName2']:
        parentNode = element.parentNode
        parentNode.insertBefore(doc.createComment(element.toxml()), element)
        parentNode.removeChild(element)
f = open(myXmlFile, "w")
f.write(doc.toxml())
f.close()
```

*Thanks @Ivo Bosticky*

Answer (score 1):

While using regexps with HTML is bad, matching a string that does not contain a given pattern is an interesting question in itself.

Let's assume that we want to match a string beginning with an `a` and ending with a `z` and take out whatever is in between only when string `bar` is not found inside.

Here's my take: `"a((?:(?<!ba)r|[^r])+)z"`

It basically says: find `a`, then find either an `r` which is not preceded by `ba`, or something different than `r` (repeat at least once), then find a `z`. So, a `bar` cannot sneak in into the catch group.

Note that this approach uses a 'negative lookbehind' pattern and only works with lookbehind patterns of fixed length (like `ba`).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using BeautifulSoup for this. It's a python HTML/XML parser.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you want to remove the P tags which don't have closing tags.
However, if this is an attempt to clean code, an advantage of BeautifulSoup is that is can clean HTML for you:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<td><p>111</td>
<td><p>111<p>222</p></td>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()
```

this doesn't get rid of your unmatched tags, but it fixes the missing ones.